# Release Apps For iPhone only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

i have done developed an apps, preparing for submission currently. The apps is actually developed for iPhone/iPod only. I have go to Xcode, target -> Build Settings -> Targeted Device Family,but the available option selection is either 1 or 2, which option should i select in order to make the app available for iPhone only?

Answer (score 4):

open your project target - > genereal - > device Info --> devices --> iphone

for sample

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks, yup i have already set it to iPhone but when i upload to iTunes connect they still require me to upload iPad's screenshot.

Comment: @S.Wei - not required, ok do like follow my step and generate new build with new build no , and upload the ipa to appstore and check once bro

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Anbu's answer, there is something you should be aware of.

This drop down box saying iPhone or iPad (or both) does not itself determine what platforms your app runs on, or who it should be shown to on the market.

You can't run normal iPad apps on an iPad Pro without modification. How does Apple know you want to offer it to iPad Pro customers? They check to see if you have uploaded iPad Pro screenshots. Same with every variation in iDevices.

If it is complaining, as Anbu said its probably because you have indicated in your Project that it should also run on some platform (like iPads) but not uploaded screenshots which would allow it to be offered to iPad customers. Easily fixed.